# Resource Monitor Disk Queue Length - What does the green graph and blue line represent?

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance, performance-monitor

Windows Resource Monitor shows a graph of **Disk Queue Length**. E.g.:

[image]

What does the **green** graph, and the **blue** line represent:

[image]

## Research Effort

- [In the Resource Monitor of Windows 7, what does the "disk queue length" really mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/331973/in-the-resource-monitor-of-windows-7-what-does-the-disk-queue-length-really-m) *(it's not **Disk I/O** and **Highest Active Time**)*
- https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/use-resource-monitor-to-monitor-storage-performance/
- Technet: [Performance and Reliability Monitoring Getting Started Guide for Windows Server 2008](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771692(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/280844/resource-monitor-disk-usage-scale

### It is **not** Disk I/O and Highest Active Time

Don't forget, it is **not** `Disk I/O` and `Highest Active Time`, because it can't be both things for both graphs. Because both graphs are different.

[image]

- if it were the same thing
- for both graphs
- then both graphs would be the same

Also, one graph is Disk I/O (in MB/sec), and the other is Queue Length (in number).

Comment: " it can't be both things for both graphs." Why not?.....https://superuser.com/questions/45722/what-does-highest-active-time-for-disk-activity-in-windows-resource-monitor-me

Comment: @Moab If both lines represented the same thing, then both graphs would look the same (since they are measuring the same thing). Since they don't look the same - something has to be different.

Answer (score 2):

Green is the Disk I/O in KB/second

Blue is % Highest active time

[image]

Comment: If they are Disk I/O and Highest Active Time in the **Queue Length** graph; what are they in the top graph?

Comment: Don't have a clue.

Comment: They the same in the top graph - the blue graph is identical on all displays.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 fixed the issue, and the confusion.

The confusion was that:

- each **Physical Disk** had a blue line
- which supposedly represented *"highest active time"*

But then how can every Physical Disk have the **same** highest active time?

Answer: they don't. The blue line has nothing to do with any particular physical disk.

So in Windows 10 the blue line was removed from everything except the aggregated *pseudo*-physical disk **"Disk"**.